# How to get multiple counts with multiple joins using one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

There is an error in my query and I would like some help. I have three tables

1. Rooms{id,number,name,type(ECO/LUX),active(0/1)}
2. Men{passport,roomid,status(YOUTH/ADULT)}
3. Women{passport,roomid,status(YOUTH/ADULT)}

**In each room there can be more than one woman or man.

I want to count how many women and men have the same room with roomid in (1,2,3), status='ADULT', type='LUX' and active=1. Therefore I need a result like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------+----------+------------+
| id | number |   name    | CountMen | CountWomen |
+----+--------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1  |     23 | 1st suite |        2 |          4 |
| 3  |      4 | 2nd suite |        1 |          2 |
+----+--------+-----------+----------+------------+

SELECT id,number,name,
sum(case when Men.status='ADULT' then 1 else 0 end) as CountMen,
sum(case when Women.status='ADULT' then 1 else 0 end) as CountWomen
FROM Rooms left join Men
on Rooms.id=Men.roomid
left join Women on Room.id=Women.roomid where
(type='LUX') and (active=true) and (id in (1,2,3))
group by id;
```

The problem is that I get sometimes wrong results in the counters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `left join`, conditions on the *second* table need to be in the `on` clause.  It would help if you qualified *all* column names in the query.

However your problem is because you are getting a Cartesian product between the gender tables.  This is definitely a case where gender segregation is not a good thing.  You should have just one table for *people* (and this doesn't even bring up other issues with defining binary genders).

```
SELECT r.id, r.number, r.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM men m
        WHERE m.status = 'ADULT' AND r.id = m.roomid
       ) as CountMen,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM women w
        WHERE w.status = 'ADULT' AND r.id = w.roomid
       ) as CountWomen
FROM Rooms r 
WHERE r.type = 'LUX' AND r.active = true AND r.id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

However, you should fix your data model so you have *people* rather than segregated gender tables.

Comment: Thank you very much.I really appreciate your help. This is just the structure and not the tables at all.